# Encode UTF-8 not working when retrieving Xpath text

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I'm retrieving some date from a website via lxml xpath:

```
page = requests.get(url)

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

titles_arr = tree.xpath("//span[@class='lister-item-header']/span/a/text()")
```

Some of the titles have German Umlaute (e.g. `üöä`) so I thought of encoding the text returned like so:

```
for title in titles_arr:
    title = title.encode('utf-8')
```

but it still consists of like `Der Herr der Ringe - Die R\u00fcckkehr des K\u00f6nigs` instead of their respective unicode character. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: To me, it seems unclear what `tree` and what `xpath` is. What library is it? There seem to be several libraries featuring an `xpath` method... Not a [mcve].

Comment: @AndreyTyukin using lxml for it

Comment: How exactly are you obtaining that output…?

Comment: @deceze requests module

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be dealing with a bytestring encoded with unicode characters escaped.

You can decode like this:

```
>>> bs = b'Die R\u00fcckkehr des K\u00f6nigs'
>>> bs.decode('raw-unicode-escape')
'Die Rückkehr des Königs'
```

If you are dealing with text, rather than bytes, you'll need to encode then decode:

```
>>> s = 'Die R\u00fcckkehr des K\u00f6nigs'                                                                                                                                                                                               
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('raw-unicode-escape')                                                                           
'Die Rückkehr des Königs'
```

This kind of encoding is used to escape unicode characters in json, to restrict the json to ascii values:

```
>>> json.dumps('Die Rückkehr des Königs')
'"Die R\\u00fcckkehr des K\\u00f6nigs"'
```

so it's possible that whatever url you are fetching is html with embedded json, or json with embedded html - it might be worth checking the response's `json` attribute.

Comment: appreciate your answer but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried both of your ways and they don't work. I am looping through the list and do `encode('latin-1').decode('raw-unicode-escape')` and it dumps the JSON with `\u00fc` and `\u00f6`.

Comment: @supersize what is the url that you are fetching?  And Python2 or Python3?

Comment: `https://www.imdb.com/search/title?groups=top_1000&sort=user_rating&view=simple&page=1` please notice that this link might have different content depending on the country you are in. So it might be that you don't have `üöä`, Python2

Comment: I can retrieve the German text with `page = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept-Language': 'de-DE'})`.  Response has content-language `'de-DE'`, content-type `'text/html;charset=UTF-8'`.  Running your sample code in the interpreter, I see hex escapes (`Die R\xfcckkehr des K\xf6nigs`) for each title's `repr`, expected values (`Die Rückkehr des Königs`) if `print`ed.  Python 2.7.14, requests 2.19.1, lxmll 4.2.4, Linux.

Comment: so what are you telling me, sorry?

Comment: @supersize that I can't reproduce your issue if I retrieve German text from imdb.